# Reduce a set of intervals to simplest representation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of "intervals" defined as a list of tuples. I am currently looping through the entire list of intervals and comparing each one to check if a value is in coverage. However because my list of intervals is very large (with a lot of overlap) this is doing a lot of unnecessary work.

For a simplified example:

```
def in_coverage(x, intervals)
    for start, end in intervals:
        if start <= x <= end:
            return True
    return False

intervals = [(1, 3), (3, 4)]
in_coverage(2, intervals) # => True
in_coverage(7, intervals) # => False
```

So, in order to reduce the amount of work done by this check I would like to perform a reduction on the list of intervals up front.

How can I efficiently reduce my set of intervals into their simplest representation?

For example:

```
[(1, 3), (3, 4)] => [(1, 4)]
[(1, 3), (3, 4), (2, 5), (7, 8), (9, 11)] => [(1, 5), (7, 8), (9, 11)]
```

Comment: How is `(7,8),(9,11) -> (7,11)` ? Aren't you missing `(8,9)` ?

Comment: Woops, you're right. Sorry, I'll update the examples.

Comment: Are the numbers (both the endpoints and the values that you want to check for coverage) always integers? If so, I would think that you could get by with much simpler code then in the float case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple representation that you are looking for relies a simple observation: if you sort the tuple by low-value then overlapping intervals are adjacent*. Of course there is a caveat, if there are multiple overlaps then two overlapping intervals can be separated by a chain of intervals, but only if the chain is connected. Interval Graphs have some pretty cool properties.

Anyway, this means that you can merge overlapping intervals in a single greedy scan of the sorted list. In pseudo-code something like:

`foreach interval in list
  if it overlaps current
    current = combined bounds are simple convex hull
              min(current low,interval low), max(current high, interval high)
  else
    current is finished, append to result
    current = interval`

This takes care of minimising the number of intervals in the representation. If you want to maximise the lookup speed then the tree suggested by Ami Tavory is the way to go (I would also guess that his library takes care of this reduction in the size of the interval set implicitly during tree construction). There are a few other python packages that do the same thing: sparse interval set libraries. Try googling for "intervalset python" and check that it doesn't autocorrect it to something similar. I've used pyinter before and it seemed to be small, fast and with a simple interface. Banyan looks more powerful but it certainly does what you want - maybe Ami Tavory could cut'n'paste the 3-line example that shows how to setup and query an integer interval into his answer for clarity?

Answer (score 2):

For your type of queries, an [Interval Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) can make things much more efficient. One way to do so is using a tree ordered by the 'low' values of the intervals, and an extra annotation is added to every node recording the maximum high value among the tree: the node's high value and the high values of both its subtrees (see more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#Augmented_tree) or in CLRS).

I wrote a [PyPI package, banyan](http://pythonhosted.org/Banyan/), which also does this stuff (see [here](http://pythonhosted.org/Banyan/reference.html#predf-node-updators)). It supports exactly your type of queries.

Comment: It certainly does, but it also does a lot of things. Perhaps a 3-line example of how to setup and query integer intervals would add some clarity?

Answer (score 1):

In the special case that all of the numbers involved are integers you could create the set of covered points as soon as you create your list of intervals and just check if your number is in the set of covered points:

```
def makeCoverSet(intervals):
    s = set()
    for (a,b) in intervals:
        s.update(range(a,b+1))
    return s

intervals = [(1, 3), (3, 4)]

coverage = makeCoverSet(intervals)

print(2 in coverage) #prints True
print(5 in coverage) #prints False
```